# Copy Cells in One Column, Based on Criteria in Another Column, to Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy entries from a column based on data from another column to another sheet.

I have the following data on Sheet1

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4 
J           1
K           2
L           3           X            W
M           4
N           5
O           6           Y            Z
```

I have the following data on Sheet2

```
Column 1
A
B
C
D
```

I want check if there is a value in Column 3 from Sheet 1 and copy the entry in Column 1 to the bottom of Column 1 from Sheet 2.

I want Sheet 2 to look like this:

```
Column 1
A
B
C
D
"FROM SHEET 1"
L
O
```

L and O appear because they have a value in Column 3 from Sheet 1.

I defined the bottom rows of both sheets and am trying to evaluate by setting a range Column3A:lastrow and evaluating if the cells in column 3 <>"".
The copy doesn't  work and I'm not sure that it will paste how I want.

```
Dim rownum5 As Long, rownum6 As Long
rownum5 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
rownum6 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E" & rownum6)
    For Each cell In r1
        If cell.Value <> "" Then cell.Offset(0, -3).Copy
        .Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & rownum5 + 1)
    Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

I think the `for each cell in r1` doesn't locate the right cells.

Comment: You need to show us the code you're using...

Comment: I've updated to what I have, any suggestions?

Comment: This can be done with in-cell formulas. You have a reason why you want this to happen via VBA? Also, what is the role of column 2 and 4, and the values in sheet 2 in light of the question? Could you not remove all that in the context of this question?

Comment: I do need this as a macro unfortunately, and yes the extra columns in Sheet 1 don't really matter in this case but that's exactly how it is on my sheet. For sheet 2 I just wanted to show it needed to go below existing data.

Answer (score -1):

I quickly wrote this macro, it seems to be working fine for me given your data format

it just pastes the column 1 of sheet 1 to the end of column 1 in sheet 2

```
Sub main()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 30
    If IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value) = False Then

    Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange 'refreshes sheet2
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row 'find the number of used rows

    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Offset(0, -2).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(LastRow, 0) 'copies and pastes the data

Else
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

it's probably not the most elegant way to get to the last row but it does work.

Comment: Hi I don't think you're understanding what I need to do.

Comment: So when there's a value in column 3 you want it to copy the value in column 1 to sheet 2?

Comment: yeah that's what the code does, I realise I didn't word my answer that well. give it a try and let me know if that works for you