# VBA Excel If some value occur in the column, copy it to another column in the same row

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with the following situation.

I have a set of bulk data in column U, from which I must filter the "missing pole" value.
Next, I must copy this "missing pole" value to column BN, exactly to the same row, where it occurs in column U, as you can see below.

[image]

I tried:

```
Sub Flag()
  Dim lRow As Long
  If Range("U2:U" & lRow).Value = "Missing pole" Then
  Range("U2:U" & lRow).Copy
  Range("BN2:BN" & lRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  End If
End Sub
```

but I am getting error:

> Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed.

Debugger shows:

```
  If Range("U2:U" & lRow).Value = "Missing pole" Then
```

Other threads are here:

[Copy Cells in One Column, Based on Criteria in Another Column, to Another Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065914/copy-cells-in-one-column-based-on-criteria-in-another-column-to-another-sheet)

[VBA - IF a cell in column A = Value, then copy column B, C, D of same row to new worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53623314/vba-if-a-cell-in-column-a-value-then-copy-column-b-c-d-of-same-row-to-new)

but without a reasonable solution for me.

How can I copy the certain value occurring in the column (throughout a whole range) to another column placing it exactly in the same row?

Comment: You are not setting `lRow` to anything, so its value is `0` - and `Range("U2:U0")` is not a valid `Range`.

Comment: So how can I set the lRow here?

Comment: Well, what row are you trying to find? The last one? One that contains a certain value? There are lots of ways of finding a row value.

Comment: I have the "missing pole" values across the whole U column down to the last row. I need them to be copied to BN column in the same row roughly.

Comment: @braX your answer was about to be upvoted as I tested the code you removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the VBA code that would work fine.
> *The Error is because you are trying to value of Range object you just need a For loop to traverse all the rows and then check if there is any value with "Missing Pole"*

**Here is the code:**

```
Sub Flag()
  Dim LastRow As Long
  With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
  End With
  For i = 2 To LastRow
    If ActiveSheet.Range("U" & i) = "Missing pole" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("BN" & i).Value2 = ActiveSheet.Range("U" & i).Value2
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: OK I found an error. It should be "Missing Pole" instead.
How about multitude values in this range?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the If statement case insensitive this way:

```
Sub Flag()
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim lLastRow As Long

  lLastRow = Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For lRow = 2 To lLastRow 
    If UCase$(Range("U" & lRow).Value) = "MISSING POLE" Then
      
      ' do what you want here

    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: In your code:
Instead of 
Range("U2:U" & lRow).Copy
      Range("BN2:BN" & lRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
it should be
Range("BN2:BN" & lRow).Value = Range("U" & lRow).Value

otherwise the whole column is copied.